# What is one standard way to document a Context provider in React.js

Tags: reactjs, documentation, storybook

I am writing a Context provider in React.js, and am stuck when it comes to documenting it. Is there a standard way to do that?
What I'm looking for is something similar to component documentation using PropTypes, where you put comments on top of each `prop-type`, as well as on top of the component's definition.
It is preferable if the solution is supported by `react-storybook`

Comment: I would recommend JSDocs. https://www.inkoop.io/blog/a-guide-to-js-docs-for-react-js/  This will also support react-storybook, the documentation you will write here, will show up on story-book as well

Comment: @Nayan shah  What I'm looking for is something for React context, not components.

Comment: Hey, did you find the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a standard way, but at least for me it works:

AuthContextProvider.js

```js
...
const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  /** @type {import('firebase/auth').User} Current (Firebasle) user instance */
  user: null,
  /** @type {boolean} True if current user has access to the app */
  hasAccess: null,
  /** @type {Function} Perform logout from firebase */
  logOut,
});

const useAuth = () => {
  const { user, hasAccess } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return { user, hasAccess, logOut };
};
...
```

[image]